# MongoDB. Match by date from field in same record

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have data like:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("4c02c58de500fe1be1000005"),
created_at: 2021-11-13T16:11:34.751+00:00,
"text" : "some text",
"events" : [
    {"id":"1", created_at: 2021-12-13T16:11:34.751+00:00},
    {"id":"2", created_at: 2021-12-13T16:11:36.751+00:00}
    {"id":"3", created_at: 2021-10-13T16:11:38.751+00:00}

]
}
```

I have next aggregation:
db.collection.aggregate([

```
[
{'$unwind': {'path': '$events'}}, 
{'$match': {'events.created_at': {'$gt': 'created_at'}}},
{'$group': {'_id': '$id', 'events': {'$push': '$events'}, 'data': {'$first': '$$ROOT'}}}, 
{'$addFields': {'data.nbr_of_new_events_since_last_clicked': 
{'$size': '$events'}}}, {'$replaceRoot': {'newRoot': '$data'}}
]
```

In output i expect:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("4c02c58de500fe1be1000005"),
created_at: 2021-11-13T16:11:34.751+00:00,
"text" : "some text",
"events" : [
    {"id":"1", created_at: 2021-12-13T16:11:34.751+00:00},
    {"id":"2", created_at: 2021-12-13T16:11:36.751+00:00}
    {"id":"3", created_at: 2021-10-13T16:11:38.751+00:00}

],
nbr_of_new_events_since_last_clicked: 2
}
```

When i run this query i have empty results. I think this is because i use

> {'$match': {'events.created_at': {'$gt': 'created_at'}}}

not in bson format. How i can fix it?

Will be grateful for the help

Comment: You need to use `$expr` when matching fields from within the same document. Note that you also need to use `$eq` aggregation operator in this case.

Comment: @prasad_ yes, it help. Please, write you comment like answer and i accept and vote for it.